# How can I change the default currency key on Swype keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s, swype

In Swype Settings I have the language set to "UK English" yet for some reason when I'm typing the currency symbol (long-press on <kbd>s</kbd>) is a dollar sign (**$**) not a pound sign (**£**), if I press <kbd>SYM</kbd> the dollar actually has its own button <kbd>$</kbd> on the left-hand side, and I have Euro (€) and Yen on the top row for long presses on <kbd>#</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd>, and the pound is relegated to the right hand side for a long-press on <kbd>"</kbd>.

Is there any way that I can set it to replace the **$** on the main screen with a **£** sign, and replace the dollar on its own button on the symbol screen with a pound sign?

Am using the built-in Swype keyboard *(v1.64.40.9754)* on a Vodafone UK Samsung Galaxy S *(Eclair 2.1 update 1, build JM4)*.

Comment: You may need to file a bug report or feature request on their forums: http://forum.swype.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have done http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?1343-Default-currency-key-doesn-t-change will keep an eye out there, assuming no one here knows how to change this behaviour?

Comment: I use Swype, but I'm from the US.  It sounds like a locale problem that the devs need to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with the version of Swype pre-installed by Samsung. I have logged a bug on Swype's forums [here](http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?1343-Default-currency-key-doesn-t-change). Don't think there's anything much any of us can do now except wait for Swype to fix the bug and for Samsung to push out the updated version.

*(just adding this as an answer and accepting to get this off the unanswered questions list, if anyone has a better solution please post and I'll transfer the acceptance over)*

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the Swype theme after you have selected your default language.

Comment: This is suitable as a comment. Consider raising your reputation points to 50+ to comment anywhere.